# Google Chrome 60.0.3112.90 VueJS response.data bug

Tags: json, ajax, google-chrome, vue.js

I am using VueJS and the `$http` package to do API calls to my website. However, it seems that on Google Chrome 60.0.3112.90, the `data` property of the Response object no longer parses the received JSON and instead passes back a string.

Is this a bug in Google Chrome? The site was working fine yesterday and with no changes, no ajax call works today. I can only assume its the new version of Chrome as the latest FireFox works just fine.

Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 5):

After some more digging, it seems that `vue-resource` does not handle lowercase http headers. I fixed the issue using the interceptor at the following link:

https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/314

Hopefully this helps anyone else with the same/similar issues